# Converting SVG to PNG without knowing the width and height

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, base64, svgtopng

I am trying to convert an SVG to a PNG image using the canvas as the "proxy". I can get it to work in Chromium, but not in Firefox. It seams that I need a width and height defined in the SVG, but in my case the SVG does not have width and height attributes. When the SVG is displayed in the browser the size depends on the size of the container/window.

The SVGs are converted to PNG successfully, but this one [shell SVG](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Hra44q-2upJ4zqNzPCaNKJ981kT7IWKD/view?usp=sharing).

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8mqtLw6p/

```js
var img = new Image();
var svg = new Blob([svgString], {
  type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"
});
var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);
img.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  var png = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  var mg = document.createElement("img");
  mg.setAttribute("src", png);
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  document.body.appendChild(mg);
  DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(png);
};
img.setAttribute("src", url);
```

Comment: Running the JS fiddle, there is `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'serializeToString' on 'XMLSerializer': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.` After fixing that (I just added an "id" attribute to the svg tag, like `<svg id="container" ...`), it seems to work properly. What do you find that "does not work"? Does the output look weird or is there no output?

Comment: @qrsngky Thank you for noticing. It's my bad for not checking the error before posting. I have updated JSFiddle link. The issue is the canvas is empty.

Comment: @NgọcNguyễn It's executing correctly on the most recent version of Chrome on Windows. Where is it failing for you?

Comment: @DavidMulder It's not working on FireFox.

Comment: I managed to make the canvas draw something on Firefox by specifying width and height attributes for the `<svg`, like `width="1040" height="487"` .

Comment: @qrsngky Just came to answer the same  No idea what's going on with Firefox there.

Comment: It's a bit strange that Firefox fails to compute the width and height of an SVG for a canvas (when they are not specified as attributes) when it can get them in other contexts. To get the same effect as in Chromium, you may need to manually calculate them based on the viewBox and the dimensions of the canvas.

Comment: @qrsngky FireFox fails us this time. Adding CSS to add size to the SVG does not work. Adding the `width` and `height` attributes works as you said.

Comment: Did you have a look at some of the other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70309786/how-to-render-svg-and-convert-to-png-in-react-native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to draw a bitmap image it needs a size (width and height). If the SVG does not have a size specified and you would like to copy it as it is rendered in the browser you can use [getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to get the width and height.

Now, that you SVG is rather big I just replaced all the paths with a circle and modified the viewBox a bit.

```js
let svg01 = document.getElementById('Capa_1');
let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let img01 = document.getElementById('img01');

let BCR = svg01.getBoundingClientRect();
svg01.setAttribute('width', BCR.width);
svg01.setAttribute('height',BCR.height);

var xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer();
var svgString = xmlSerializer.serializeToString(svg01);

var svg = new Blob([svgString], {
  type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"
});
var url = URL.createObjectURL(svg);

let img = new Image();

img.addEventListener('load', e => {
  URL.revokeObjectURL(e.target.src);
  canvas.width = e.target.width;
  canvas.height = e.target.height;
  ctx.drawImage(e.target, 0, 0);
  img01.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
});
img.src = url;
```

```html
<h3>The SVG:</h3>
<svg id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 80 60">
  <style type="text/css">.st0 { fill: rgb(222, 83, 81); }.st1 { fill: rgb(23, 89, 149); }.st2 { fill: none; stroke: rgb(222, 83, 81); stroke-width: 2; stroke-miterlimit: 10; }.st3 { fill: rgb(33, 37, 88); }.st4 { fill: rgb(177, 223, 239); }.st5 { fill: rgb(255, 255, 255); }</style>
  <circle class="st1" cx="40" cy="30" r="25" />
</svg>
<hr>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<div>
  <img id="img01" />
</div>
```